# Why can't I insert data from a form into my Database with PDO bind_param

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, bindparam

First here is my code:

**database.php** (established connection so I can use with require)

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$port = 8889;
$database = "oopdb";

try{
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername; dbname=$database; port=$port", $username, $password);
 // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

}catch(Exception $e){
      echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }
?>
```

**Then my main PHP file with the form:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Forms with PDO</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php 

require("database.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

//trying to insert data into the database
try{

  // prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO clients (phonenumber, firstname, lastname, address, note) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssss', $phonenumber, $firstname, $lastname, $address, $note);

// set parameters and execute
$phonenumber = $_POST['number'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$note = $_POST['note'];
$stmt->execute();

}catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Data could not be retrieved from the database.";
        exit;
    }
}
?>

<h2>The Form</h2>
<hr />
<br />
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
Number: <input type="text" name="number" value="" />
<br /><br />
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" />
<br /><br />
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" />
<br /><br />
Address: <input type="text" name="address" value="" />
<br /><br />
Notes: <input type="text" name="notes" value="" />
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br />
<hr />

</body>
</html>
```

So now for some reason I am not able to insert the data from the form into my database when I click submit. I keep getting this error:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() in /Users/lucasantos/Sites/oop_testing/stack.php on line 19**

I have seen multiple ways of using bind_param and inserting data into the database. This method in specific I got from W3schools [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

I have went over the entire code multiple times, tried many times and still not working. I even looked at the bind_param documentation and I believe I am using it correctly. Someone please help.

**Some additional information:**

*- I am doing this on local host through MAMP if that matters.*

*- I also have a column for the **id** of the row but I did not include it because it is set to auto increment.*

Thank you!

Comment: You're mixing up PDO and mysqli here. [Have a look-see at how to bind params with PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: can you please elaborate on that because I have seen tutorials where they use this exact method. Not with bind_param but with the way they establish connection.

Comment: You're using the [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) function from the MySQLi driver. Whereas you should be using the PDO [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). Your problem isn't in the logic, it's literally in the syntax. change `bind_param` to `bindParam` and lose the `'sssss'`, that's not how you'd bind parameters with PDO.

Comment: i'd suggest this one http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#INSERT.2C_DELETE.2C_UPDATE_Prepared_Queries instead of w3schools

Comment: Thank you both very much, unfortunately iv ran into another terrible error aside from the bindParam and thought it would need a whole question of it's own. I posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232682/keep-getting-error-when-trying-inserting-form-data-into-database-with-pdo