# Keep getting error when trying inserting form data into database with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, error-handling

First here is my code:

**database.php** (established connection so I can use with require)

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$port = 8889;
$database = "oopdb";

try{
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername; dbname=$database; port=$port", $username, $password);
 // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

}catch(Exception $e){
      echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }
?>
```

**Then my main PHP file with the form:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Forms with PDO</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php 

require("database.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

try{

  // prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO clients (phonenumber, firstname, lastname, address, note) VALUES (:phonenumber, :firstname, :lastname, :address, :note)");
$stmt->bindParam(':phonenumber', $phonenumber, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':address', $address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':note', $note, PDO::PARAM_STR);


    // set parameters and execute
if(isset($_POST['phonenumber'])){ $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber']; }
if(isset($_POST['firstname'])){ $firstname = $_POST['firstname']; }
if(isset($_POST['lastname'])){ $lastname = $_POST['lastname']; }
if(isset($_POST['address'])){ $address = $_POST['address']; }
if(isset($_POST['note'])){ $note = $_POST['note']; }
$stmt->execute();

}catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "$e";
        exit;
    }
}
?>

<h2>The Form</h2>
<hr />
<br />
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
Number: <input type="text" name="number" value="" />
<br /><br />
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" />
<br /><br />
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" />
<br /><br />
Address: <input type="text" name="address" value="" />
<br /><br />
Notes: <input type="text" name="notes" value="" />
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br />
<hr />

</body>
</html>
```

So I am trying to INSERT the data from my form into my database but I keep getting this error:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1048 Column 'phonenumber' cannot be null' in
>   /Users/lucasantos/Sites/oop_testing/form.php:32 Stack trace: #0
>   /Users/lucasantos/Sites/oop_testing/form.php(32):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main}

Really do not understand what is going on here, I have re checked the code and checked the error online and can't find anything relavant. Please help.

**Some additional information:**

*- I am doing this on local host through MAMP if that matters.*

*- I also have a column for the **id** of the row but I did not include it because it is set to auto increment.*

Thank you!

Comment: This means in the table definition you have set `not null` for `phonenumber`, alter the table and set it as `null`

Comment: I did that and it worked! only one problem though. The Phonenumber and Note that I have typed in my form is not what shows in the database table. It shows phonenumber and note as NULL in my table (but not the rest of the data)

Comment: Your form field is named `number`, but you are checking for `$_POST['phonenumber']`

Comment: Same with `note` and `notes`.

Comment: Darn typos. Thank you so much you guys really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using the html input name as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="number" value="" />
```

But in your php code, you are using a different name for your phone number field

```
// set parameters and execute
if(isset($_POST['phonenumber'])){ $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber']; }
```

Change your HTML name of the input filed to "phonenumber" and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up billgwakisa really appreciate it. @nlu pointed that out for me. Thanks again